# First appearance of specific key in subhashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array:

```
array = [{"number" => "7", "disk" => "70"},{"number" => "12", "disk" => "150", "global" => "yes"},{"number" => "8", "disk" => "250", "global" => "yes"}]
```

I want to define a string containing the value of the first "global" key appearance. I know how to loop over that hash, but I can't figure out how to define the first appearance of that key.

Comment: That structure is invalid. It's not a hash.

Comment: What string do you mean by "a string containing xxx"? There are infinitely many such strings.

Comment: sawa You're right, I've corrected it.
I mean a string e.g. str = the value of frist appearance of key "global"

Answer (score 1):

```
array.each { |h| break h["global"] if h["global"] }
```